# How to retrieve current workspace path in RCP 4 app?

Tags: java, path, eclipse-rcp, e4

In my RCP 4 app, how can I retrieve the workspace path of the app? I tried some but failed:

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot(); //Cannot used in RCP 4 app
URL fileURL = FileLocator.find(Platform.getProduct().getDefiningBundle(),new Path("/"), null); //is not workspace
Location instanceLocation = Platform.getInstanceLocation(); // the same as getInstallLocation()
String s = System.getProperty("eclipse.workspace"); //
```

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Platform.getInstanceLocation()` should work but you will have to add code in the startup to set a location if one is not set by specifying the `-data` command line option.

Something like:

```
Location instanceLoc = Platform.getInstanceLocation();
// TODO check for null

if (!instanceLoc.isSet()) {
  URL url = .... work out a location for the workpace 

  instanceLoc.set(url, false);
}
```

I run code like this in the `@PostContextCreate` method of the LifeCycle class.

Note: Do not call the `Location.getURL` method until you have set the location as described above. Calling `getURL` before doing this will set a default of the install location (which is what you testing is showing).